# Is it possible to change the billingDayOfMonth of braintree subscriptions?

Tags: paypal, braintree

From the documentation it appears that I can only set the `billingDayOfMonth` when I create a subscription. but I don't see that option when updating a subscription.

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/php
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/update/php

Is there another way of doing this? Or do I have to cancel a subscription and create a new one? I'd prefer not to do that but not sure what my options are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Your initial conclusion is correct — once a subscription has been created, the [billing date cannot be updated](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/billing-cycles#changing-the-billing-date). You will have to create a new subscription, but you can specify a [custom subscription ID](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/create/php#id) that links the new one to the canceled one if that helps you keep track of things.

Comment: Awesome! I totally missed that you can set the ID. This works just as well as what I needed. thanks a bunch